# Display progressbar while saving records to database

Tags: vb.net

How to show the progressbar while updating 10-30 thousand records in ms access database.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, maybe avoiding THE ALL CAPS SUBJECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details I can only offer a list of operation to be done:

- First you need to know how many  modified/inserted record are
  present.
- Then you should subscribe to the event RowUpdated of your
  OleDbDataAdapter.
- Set the progressbar initial value to zero and the maximum value to
  the count of modified records.
- In the RowUpdated event increment by one your progress bar value.

[See for reference the OleDbDataAdapter docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter_methods%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks steve it was done using RowUpdated event of OledbDataAdapter.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If my answer helped you remember to mark it as accepted.